# Can I restrict geocode results to a specific state in R?

Tags: r, ggmap, geocode

I'm using the ggmap geocode with the Google maps API. I have vector of city names in Ohio (city), and I am trying to return coordinates for each of these cities. My code,

```
coordinates <- geocode(city)
```

Is mostly returning the correct coordinates, but many of the city names in Ohio are the same as those in other states, so I'm receiving a few incorrect coordinates. Is there an argument I can add to "geocode" so that it only returns coordinates from Ohio?

Thanks!

Comment: You can add Ohio to city name prior to geocode.  Like with this “paste0(city, “, OH”)”

Comment: perfect, thank you!